# Java Form based authentication failing over HTTPS

Tags: java, validation, https, weblogic12c

I have case where my web application working fine using form based authentication over HTTP, same is failing when i access over HTTPS, even if i enter correct username and password it is always redirecting to error page.

I have deployed application as EAR on weblogic 12c application server, will be accessing by web server.

How can we check whether username and password reaching application server correctly for validation.?

Please suggest me solution.

### Web.xml

```
<login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
                    <form-login-config>
                        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page> 
                        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page> 
                    </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

Comment: check your log files - what error is being reported?

Comment: This is not enough information.